# Import csv data for filter

Tags: powershell, csv

I am new to programming with PowerShell and am trying to add a filter.
this data I got from a external source and is delivered as a csv.

In the csv is only a list of location files that have to be filtered out

```
$InputFilePath = "C:\Users\input"
$OutputFilePath = "C:\Users\output"

$file_filter = @(Import-Csv -Header filter -Path $OutputFilePath\ExportProcessedFiles_2.csv)
    

Get-ChildItem  $InputFilePath -Filter *.XML -exclude $file_filter |
```

The xml looks like

[image]

Removing the `-exclude` will do all the files which is not the intention.
so I can't get my head wrapped around it, am i missing something or am i using the wrong command.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the CSV file looks like. What is a "location file"? If it's not actually a CSV, but simply a text file containing a file name on each line, then you can simply do `$file_filter = Get-Content $OutputFilePath\ExportProcessedFiles.csv` instead

Comment: i have updated it with the requested information, i hope this helps to make it more clear

Comment: Clear as day, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `-Header filter` since your CSV file *already has a `filter` header*.

The `-Exclude` parameter expects an array of file names, not an array of objects with a `filter` property, so make sure to grab just the file names themselves - you can use either `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`, or `ForEach-Object -MemberName` for this:

```
$file_filter = Import-Csv -Path $OutputFilePath\ExportProcessedFiles_2.csv |ForEach-Object -MemberName filter

Get-ChildItem ... -Exclude $file_filter
```